# Sorting series of numbers

Tags: php

I have a series of numbers in a string like 4,5,3,6,7,8,2,1 and I want them to be in order like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I have tried using explode but been stuck since

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There a lot of basic approach to sort the data like the above case. 
You should learn Bubble Sort, Merger Sort, Selection Sort.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go,

```
$string = '4,5,3,6,7,8,2,1';

$numbers = explode(',', trim($string));
asort($numbers);
$numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

echo $numbers; // outputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

**Explanation**

- **explode()** will split a string into an array, specified by a delimiter
  (, in this case)
- **implode()** will do the opposite. It takes an array and converts into a
  string with your specified delimiter.

I had to do this to be able to order the numbers (array), by using asort() in between

Comment: What does explode and implode do? what functions are these?

Comment: Explode will split a string into an array, specified by a delimiter (, in this case)

And implode will do the opposite. 
It takes an array and converts into a string with your specified delimiter.

I had to do this to be able to order the numbers (array), by using asort() in between.

Comment: I've updated my answer with clearer formatting for you.

Answer (score 3):

Split the string into an array with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), then do a natural sort ([`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)). Finally combine the array back to a string with [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = '4,5,3,6,7,8,2,1';
$array = explode(',',$string);
natsort($array);
echo implode(',',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to convet the string in array and the sort it

```
 <?php
  $string = "4,5,3,6,7,8,2,1";
  $array  = explode(',', $string);
  asort($array);
 echo implode(',', $array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Explode` the string to an array, sort it and then `implode` it back to a string:

```
$arr = explode(',', '4,5,3,6,7,8,2,1');
sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

echo implode(',', $arr);
```